# Eclipse or Appium was unable to write uppercase character in the textbox field of my app

Tags: java, eclipse, appium

I am using Eclipse(jdk1.7.0_79) and Appium (AppiumForWindows 1.4.0.0)

I am facing an issue that when i am performing automation testing through appium and executing the code in eclipse for password field of my app. My code is:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("editPassword")).sendKeys("Top456!");
```

When I am executing above code, Eclipse was unable to write capital "T" in the textbox field. It writes "t" in textbox. Because of this issue, my app stops and unable to move forward. Please can anyone help me out.

Comment: Did you try executing `adb shell input text "Top456!"` after clicking on the `editPassword` field and check what value it's typing??? The issue may even be with your app.

Comment: its typing "top456!". I have also applied assert statement after this. Assert also mentioning that there is a error of "T".

 
Thanks

Comment: Does your app allow typing cap text in that field??? Can you try adding a cap T manually???

Comment: I have also applied assert statement after this. Assert also mentioning that there is a error of "T".

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[T]est456!> but was:<[t]op456!>

Thanks

Comment: yup i have tried, my app is allowing cap T manually